# ng-repeat with optional attribute based on repeated item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

What is the best way to get around this problem of having an optional attribute on an `ng-repeat` node:

```
<div ng-repeat="slice in pizza" mozzarella>
  {{slice.name}}
</div>
```

I only want the `mozzarella` attribute to be there at specific slices. I suspect there is no easy fix for this. Maybe there is a plugin that has a nifty way of solving the issue?

The implementation that I am looking for would possibly look similar to the ng-class directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="slice in pizza" 
     ng-optional-attr="{'mozzarella': slice.mozzarella}">
  {{slice.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: mozzarella is directive or just an attribute?

Comment: In my case a directive, but I would like a solution for both actually.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a parameter to the isolated scope of `mozzarella` that will determine if it is active:

```
<div ng-repeat="slice in pizza">
  <mozzarella isActive="true/false">{{slice.name}}</mozzarella>
</div>
```

And your directive would look something like:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('mozzarella', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      isActive: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope) {
       if(scope.isActive){
          //Do stuff
       }
       else{
         //Do other stuff
       }
    },
    templateUrl: 'mozarella.html'
  };
});
```

Comment: Do you mean like using something like `isActive="slice.active"`?

Comment: It is an external directive in my case, so I am not able to change the directive code. Otherwise this was something I could think of. Also, I cannot use any childnodes for this.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Something like that, but the OP didnt provide how he is determining active state, so I left it generic.

Comment: @JustusRomijn Please put important information like that in the question next time. Its still not an issue though, just make a new directive called `activatableMozzerlla` or something and wrap it around `Mozzerella`

Comment: @DavidGrinberg ok thanks.  I just wanted to make sure that it would still work like that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution: Use `ng-switch`

```
<div ng-repeat="slice in pizza" mozzarella>
  <div ng-switch="shouldBeMozzarella()">
      <div ng-switch-when="true"> 
        <div mozzarella>{{slice.name}}</div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="false"> 
        <div>{{slice.name}}</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I don't think this one is as good though. It complicated your HTML and has some code smell.

Comment: Yeah, the whole point is that I need that directive on the repeated node itself, not as a child. That is why it is such a complex issue.

Comment: @JustusRomijn Why? This makes no sense. You want to edit the HTML but you cant edit the HTML? That makes it an impossible task. I think you are really just getting yourself into an XY problem. Can you please post the details of your restrictions?